# jquery stopping double event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue where an prevent double events

so to start with i have a piece of code that triggers

```
jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');
```

so this listens for this trigger

```
jQuery(window).on('swipeForward', swipeHandlerNext );
```

the idea of the swipe handlers is so that a user cant swipe twice and create a double event

this would then execute the swipeHandlerNext function

```
function swipeHandlerNext(event) {

    // If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it
    if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        jQuery(".pageSize").off("swipeForward");

        // Do your stuff here
        pageSize = jQuery(".mainHeader").width();
        slide("forward", pageSize);

        console.log(" swipe complete page forward via swipe");

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    } 

    return false;
}
```

this obviously executes the slide function. this is the one that has .animate command

```
function slide(data, pageSize) {


    if (!pageSize) {
    pageSize = jQuery(".mainHeader").width();
    }

    var promise  = calcLeft(data, pageSize);


    jQuery.when(promise).then(function(result) {

        console.log(result);

        jQuery('#pageHolder').delay(500).animate({
            left: result

          }, 400, function() {
            console.log("animation started");
            calcNav(pageSize);
            calcPage(pageSize);
            jQuery(".pageSize").on("swipeForward", swipeHandlerNext);
            console.log("animation complete");

        });


    });

}
```

It is not however preventing the double slide.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why `Off()` doesn't work in your example**

jQuery's `off()` method expects the selector to [`match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

In your initial event binding you are attaching the event to the `window` element with `jQuery(window).on(...)`. But In the handler functions, you are removing and then reattaching the event to the `.pageSize` element with `jQuery('.pageSize').off(...)` and `jQuery('.pageSize').on(...)`.

In other words, at not point are you actually removing the event handler bound to the `window` element and so the user can keep on swiping.

**Why `event.handled` doesn't work in your example**

Every time the swipe event takes place, a *separate* `event` object is created and passed to the handlers. So the `event` object is not a global variable which you can modify and check for its status in subsequent swipes.

**Possible solutions following your example**

1. Match the selectors passed to the `on()` and `off()` methods.
2. Set and unset a global variable as an indication that a swipe is underway.

Comment: hi.. thanks.. this question has really stemmed from here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996012/jquery-animate-periodocially-not-running any ideas? i am pulling my hair out

Comment: @Dan On the whole, it seems to be the same issue. Updated my answer with possible solutions to the problem described in the current question. See if one of these helps.

Comment: hi - I am now using window in all the places. yes i was being thick there. the reason it doesnt work sometime is soo strange though. could it be anything to do with my swipe code? seeing as i use the function slide for both swipe events and click ones. i really dont get how it can work sometimes and othertimes not - expecially now as the events are sorted